# ViewPager - Заменить иконки на текст

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Столкнулся с проблемой и не могу решить.
Как тут произвести замену иконок на текстовые ресурс.
Допустим вместо первой иконки - текущие, вторая иконка - завершенные.

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider {

 private Context mContext;
 private final int[] ICONS = {
        R.drawable.selector_icon_active,
        R.drawable.selector_icon_inactive
 };

 public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
 }

 @Override
 public void tabUnselected(View view) {
    view.setSelected(false);
 }

 @Override
 public void tabSelected(View view) {
    view.setSelected(true);
 }

 @Override
 public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    FrameLayout customLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, parent, false);
    ((ImageView) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(ICONS[position]);
    return customLayout;
}

 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

  //  return null;
   return super.getPageTitle(position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
    return ICONS.length;
 }

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
        default:
            bundle.putSerializable("TYPE", NotificationsType.ACTIVE);
            break;
        case 1:
            bundle.putSerializable("TYPE", NotificationsType.INACTIVE);
            break;
    }
    Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
 }
}
```

**Обновление**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Лично я совсем не понял что вы таки спрашиваете. Какие иконки, какой текст, где?

Comment: Есть private final int[] ICONS там указывается ресурс на иконку.
В public View getCustomTabView(ViewGroup parent, int position) она применяется, требуется иконки заменить на текст.

Comment: Да, такая строка есть в приведённом вами коде. Что с ней не так?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я пытался создать private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Текущие", "Завершенные" }; и подключить через TextView, но не получается.

Comment: разметку custom_tab покажите

Comment: @АндройдАндройд textview2 это я добавил сам сейчас пытаясь изменить.

Comment: =)) Понятно. Ну вот, по аналогии сделайте, только будет примерно вот так customLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview2)).setText(tabTitles[position]);

Comment: @АндройдАндройд Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ((TextView) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview2)).setText(subTitles[position]);
```

где *subTitles[]* - массив типа `String` с названиями вкладок:текущие, завершенные и тд.

И из разметки уберите виджет `ImageView`, если не собираетесь его использовать (не нужны картинки)

Как-то так

Comment: Забыл поправить.